# Predicate for returning permutations of the order of elements a given list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to work out how this predicate in Prolog is working to produce permutations but I can't figure out the second predicate of sel - and was wondering whether this was clear to anyone else?

```
% permutation(L1, L2): L2 is a permutation of L1                   

permutation([], []).
permutation(L1, [X|Y]):-
   sel(L1, X, T),
   permutation(T, Y).

sel([X|Y], X, Y).
sel([X|Y], Z, [X|T]):-
   sel(Y, Z, T).
```

Answer (score 1):

`sel/3` simply find a permutation of the list splitting head and rest of the list. if you call it you get:

```
?- sel([1,2,3],A,B).
A = 1,
B = [2, 3]

A = 2,
B = [1, 3]

A = 3,
B = [1, 2]
false
```

Note that, in prolog, predicates are tested in order so if you run this

```
sel([X|Y], X, Y).
sel([X|Y], Z, [X|T]):-
    sel(Y, Z, T).

solve(L,LO):-
    findall([A,B],sel(L,A,B),LO).
```

you get

```
L = [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [1, 3]], [3, [1, 2]]]
```

But if you swap the two predicates like this

```
sel([X|Y], Z, [X|T]):-
    sel(Y, Z, T).
sel([X|Y], X, Y).

solve(L,LO):-
    findall([A,B],sel(L,A,B),LO).
```

you get

```
L = [[3, [1, 2]], [2, [1, 3]], [1, [2, 3]]]
```

and this obviously will change the result.